# Proving that a sequence of solutions of an equation is decreasing

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ the function $ f_n : x \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow x^3 + nx + n $ and $x_n$ a solution of $f_n(x_n)=0$.

I want to prove that $(x_n)$ is decreasing but classic methods doesn't work.

My first guess is that I need to use $x_n=-1-\frac{x_n^3}{n}$ but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can prove easily that for each $n$, the function $f_n$ is strictly increasing. Therefore, you have $f_n(x) > 0$ iff $x > x_n$, and $f_n(x) < 0$ iff $x < x_n$. Moreover, $f_n(-1) = -1 < 0$, so for each $n$, you have $x_n > -1$.

Now, for each $n$, 
$$f_{n+1}(x_n)=x_n^3 + (n+1)x_n + (n+1) = -n x_n -n + (n+1)x_n + (n+1) = x_n + 1 > 0$$

So you have $x_n > x_{n+1}$.